# Cannot instantiate the type Twitter

Tags: twitter

I already add the twitter4j-core-2.2.0.jar in my project build path but it still showing the error.

My code

```
Twitter twitter = new Twitter(twitter_userid,twitter_password);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [the documentation for twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)? Twitter is an interface, so it cannot be instantiated. Also, instead of the twitter password, you need to use OAuth. A lot of the API can be used anonymously, too, though.

Look at the examples I linked to, but in the end it should look something like

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
```

with the OAuth credentials in `twitter4j.properties`:

```
oauth.consumerKey=something
oauth.consumerSecret=something
oauth.accessToken=something
oauth.accessTokenSecret=something
```

Comment: I was following http://www.rominirani.com/2009/12/18/episode-13-using-the-blobstore-java-api/.. The sample was given there.

Comment: I see. Maybe they changed the API and that article is outdated now.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm actually trying uploading image to google cloud using google app engine.. Thats the only sample i found so far. Can you suggest me some link for references.